# CSS to center full-width banner image without scrollbars

Tags: html, css, image, width

I have a page where the content is 1000px wide. About halfway down on this page, I need to have an image displayed that is 600px high and 2000px wide.

This image should always be 600px high, maintain its aspect ratio and whatever can't be fit at the current browser width, should fall off equally on both the right and left (so the image stays centered as the browser window changes).

There will only be the image - nothing on top of it.

I have tried building a div and having the image fall outside of it (beyond the 1000px, but can't make it work. If I break it out of the container it works with:

```
.wideimage {
    background: url(../images/wide.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    height:600px;
}
```

This works but it would be a lot nicer if I could do it within the 1000px container and have the image fall outside to the edge of the browser window.

Answer (score 2):

To have the image fall outside the container and be centered try making it absolute, left 50% and offset the margin by half the width of the image: https://fiddle.jshell.net/7vpmndfo/1/

```
.wideimage {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-1000px;
}
```

And in order to prevent horizontal scroll bars on the browser, you would need to have you're page within a wrapper div (if it's not already) with overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variety of images and so may not know in advance the width of the image, you can centre the image with the classic "centre anything" css technique:

```
.wideimage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```